# How to disable "onchange()" on input of type number

Tags: html

I have the following input `<input type="number" placeholder="initial" min="0" max="9" required />` which accompanies the attributes `min` and `max` both from **0** to **9**

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="initial" min="0" max="9" required />
```

working perfectly, great!

### Although..

when selecting text and typing any numbers, it modifies the field. I need only the up/down selection to work through the values from 0 to 9. I tried using `readonly` but it not only disables the field, it removes the up/down selection options

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="initial" min="0" max="9" readonly required />
```

Is there any solution with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or some attribute set by default in *HTML5*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `onkeydown` with a return value `false` which prevents user inputs.

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="initial" min="0" max="9" required onkeydown="return false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input onfocus="this.blur()" type="number" placeholder="initial" min="0" max="9" required />
```

Comment: The response from friend [Nitheesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68425624/11944017) became more dynamic, but thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hi, here are some guidelines for your answer: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.